# Easier way of re-populating form data?

Tags: php, forms

Ok I'm wondering if there is any easier way of repopulating forms once they are submitted for validation?

Take this for example:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="$_POST['username']" />
```

However, it will automatically say "undefined index: username"

SO we would have to do :

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) echo $_POST['username']
```

Which is so very ugly.. is there any way of doing this? Examples are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 ways come to mind:

1. Build a helper class / function that takes the key as the argument and call `myhelper('username')`. `myhelper` will obviously contain the `isset` statement and echo or return the value if it exists, otherwise `null`
2. A slightly shorter form: `echo isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';`
3. (Don't do this) Disable notices on your server and live with it (this is only for noobs, I'd say)

Comment: This is such a good point! I'm going to build a Form object now and one that will repopulate the old value so it does all the ugly work in the background and not on the view =)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : "";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\"
         value=\"".htmlspecialchars($username)."\" />"; // VERY important!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it all inside of a reusable function:

```
function showValue($key) {
    $value = '';
    if (isset($_POST[$key])) {
        $value = $_POST[$key];
    }
    return $value;
}
```

And then use it as such:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?= showValue('username') ?>" />
```

Comment: [Hi Bobby](http://xkcd.com/327/). `Robert" /><script>alert('HAX!');</script><input type="hidden`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol This just proposes a general solution. I leave it up to them to do what they need to do to make it secure, etc. Every solution can't be a complete tutorial on PHP.

Comment: But a lot of people, especially newbie programmers, may take your code and copy-paste it literally. It's dangerous for the internet as a whole to post vulnerable code...

Comment: Then perhaps a better comment would be to mention that this snippet is not production ready and would require escaping the content to prevent XSS attacks so anyone who sees the solution would know there is more work to be done?

Comment: Normally I'd agree with that, but sadly I've worked with too many incompetent people to believe that it will work =/

Answer (score 0):

Helper function way, as short as I can make it:

```
<?php
print gv("u"); // Prints the value of $_POST['u']

function gv($n){echo(isset($_POST[$n]))?$_POST[$n]:"";}
?>
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to use such an obscure function name as "gv".

Comment: Very true.. I just wanted something short :)